# How to insert tab in a sequential word in python?

Tags: python, words, data-processing

I have a problem with a very large text file which looks like following:

```
A T T A G C A
A AT A G C A
T TT AG G A
G T T A G C A
```

Every character was split by `\t`,but some characters are connected, I want to add `\t` to these sequence. What I need is like following:

```
A T T A G C A
A A T A G C A
T T T A G C A
G T T A G C A
```

What can I do in Python? and I need to fully use my computer memory to speed up the process.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "fully use my memory". Maybe the computer memory? Splitting two characters does not require anymore that a few KB of memory...

Comment: yes，I want to speed up this procession.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input is stored in `in.txt`, an elegant solution would be

```
import re

with open('in.txt') as fin, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write('\t'.join(re.findall('\w', line))+'\n')
```

The output is stored in the file `out.txt`.

Comment: Found 2 issues with this answer.  **1.**  Open out.txt for writing: `... open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:`.    **2.**  Use fout instead of out in the write stmt: `fout.write(...)`

Comment: @clp2 Thanks for the suggestion! I've made the appropriate corrections. As a member of the site you may suggest such corrections as an edit to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write a copy of the original file like so.

```
with open('in.txt') as input, open('out.txt', 'w') as output:
    prev_char = None
    while True:
        c = input.read(1)
        if not c:
            break
        if prev_char and prev_char != '\t' and c != '\t':
            output.write('\t')
        output.write(c)
        prev_char = c
```

Comment: thanks very much,but this code might cause a problem that the first line is okay but the following lines were added \t at the first of this line.